Vehicle wont start
I have a 2012 town and country van 3.6L.
Last week I replaced my starter because it had died. Next day I was driving and stopped at a stop sign when I went to drive again the vehicle wouldn't move but it was still on. There was no noise or warning. I pushed it off the road tried restarting couldn't get it to start.
Someone suggested I replace the starter again because it was used. I replaced with a brand new one. Still wouldn't turn on. Replaced once more after advice from a 3rd mechanic so we've tried 1 used starter and 2 brand new .
Someone suggested replacing the battery, so I bought a brand new one, still didn't fix the problem.
When I try to start the vehicle best way I can describe it is it sounds like a drill. Someone else took a look and said that the starter isnt engaging the flexplate/flywheel. They said that the noise I'm hearing when attempting to start my vehicle is the starter. The starter has been checked and has no signs of even attempting to engage the flywheel.
Someone told me to check the flexplate and trying turning it..
So I tried to check the flexplate for damage, I'm able to turn it part way and then I can't turn it any farther so I'm unable to check for damage after a small area.
I have not been able to get the vehicle to turn on since then.
Any suggestions on what it could be or what I should check?
I'm in ontario(canada) and we are having the worst heat wave of the year. But in a bit im going to attempt to take it apart to get to the flex plate, so I can fully check for damage. but if the fix for this could be something that I'm just not thinking of I would love for it to be easier LOL.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
I do have a video of the noise that I can send to anyone wondering I'm just not sure how to post it here.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Remove the starter and examine its starter teeth; they should be fine and not missing any. If the starter whines with a high speed sound, this may be the one-way clutch on the starter gear, damaged and spinning because the clutch broke. Hopefully this didn't occur. Good starter clutches allow the starter gear to turn easily in one direction but not turn in the other direction; the direction for turning the engine flywheel. If you can, remove all spark plugs to eliminate compression preventing you from turning the flywheel. Without plugs, the engine should turn over with some effort. Examine the flywheel for missing teeth. Although flywheel teeth are hardened, a misaligned starter can damage starter gear or flywheel. If all's well, examine battery ground connections; between battery and chassis and chassis to engine block for severe corrosion, loose connections. Be sure the starter battery connection is clean and free of corrosion. The smaller wire to the starter is the START signal from ignition switch or electronics to power up the starter solenoid that pulls out the starter gear while closing a set of large electrical contacts to supply battery power to the starter motor. If the engine turns over without spark plugs, put them back in and try starting again.

The starter usually gets power directly from the battery with a large (low gauge) wire. It grounds by bolting to the engine/transmission and completes the circuit to the battery through a ground cable between your engine to the chassis/battery. So, if there is a weakness in this circuit (corroded wire, bad connection), you will not have consistent or strong starts.
There is also the signal wire from a relay or ECU to command the starter to engage. I have seen these connections fail more than anything else relating to a starter on some vehicles. IF this connection is corroded or weak, it will cause intermittent starts as it may not allow the starter solenoid to engage properly.
Aside from that, relays and control circuits specific to your car could be at fault and again, could cause intermittent issues.

Seems to me it's not the starter, but I've been surprised before. You probably do not have enough current going to the starter from the battery. The first thing to check is if the battery is fully charged. Even though it's new, it still may not be charged enough. Then clean both battery cables and posts at the battery with a battery cable\post cleaner. Then clean with a wire brush or sand paper the connections unhooked at the starter (battery should also be unhooked for this). Then clean the other end of the ground cable the same way. This should solve your problem.
